# Confusion on one step in proof in Achim Klenke's Probability Theory

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I've come to the following theorem and proof in Klenke's Probability Theory book, and I've hit a roadblock on the very last step of the proof. We know $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|k_n^{-1}S_{k_n}-\mathbf{E}[X_1]|=0$, but I can't figure out why $\limsup_{n\to\infty}k_n^{-1}S_{k_n}\leq \mathbf{E}[X_1].$ I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing but my brain cannot figure it out for some reason, any help would be much appreciated.

[image: part1]
[image: part2]

Comment: $\limsup_{n \to \infty}|a_n - a| = 0$ is equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n - a| = 0$, which is equivalent to $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-negative sequence $a_n$, we have $\liminf a_n \geq 0$. Thus, showing that $\limsup a_n = 0$ is enough to conclude that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n =0 $. With this in mind, the statement:

$$ \limsup_{n\to \infty} \big|k_n^{-1}S_{k_n}-E[X_1]\big| = 0 \ \text{almost surely} \tag{1}$$

Lets us conclude that:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \big|k_n^{-1}S_{k_n}-E[X_1]\big|= 0 \ \text{almost surely}$$

Which further implies that:
$$  \lim_{n\to\infty}  k_n^{-1}S_{k_n} = E[X_1] \ \text{almost surely} \tag{2}$$

When a limit exists, it is equal to the $\limsup$, so we have:

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}  k_n^{-1}S_{k_n} =\lim_{n\to\infty}  k_n^{-1}S_{k_n} = E[X_1] \ \text{almost surely} $$

Thus, the author could have actually used an equality sign.

Comment: Ok so the use of the inequality messed me up then, because I thought of this along the way but dismissed it because it gave equality and thought there would be no reason for the author to use inequality. There goes almost an hour of my life I'm not getting back lol, thank you!!